# How to fill some parts of canvas with black color in React Konva?

Tags: canvas, konvajs, react-konva

I have an image and another shape inside the canvas. The thing is, I want to highlight the area of that shape which is polygon. But, I don't want to give it any color. Instead, what I want to do is to fill all the areas outside of that shape with dark color. How can I achieve that?? Please, take a look at the demo below

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-draw-polygon-forked-uhhz0c?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Looking at your code your overlay is one big rectangle ... instead you can draw 4 going around your main rectangle

Comment: Where I am actually going to use, it's not gonna be a rectangle. It's gonna be a polygon that can have as many points as user wants and also could be any shape. I think, it will be extremely hard to implement like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Konva draws shapes inside layers on `<canvas>` elements, you can take advantage of it's `.globalCompositeOperation` property. This controls how existing content mixes with new content drawn onto the `<canvas>`.

The operation in question is called `destination-out` and keeps the content where it doesn't overlap the new content. So if we say your initial content is a simple rectangle the size of your image and the new content is the small little rectangle in your code - or any other polygon - the result will be the solid color from the first rectangle and nothing where the new shape is located.

So simply change:

```
<Layer>
    <Rect width={150} height={150} x={100} y={100} stroke="green" />
</Layer>
```

to:

```
<Layer>
    <Rect width={300} height={300} x={0} y={0} fill="green" opacity={0.5} />
    <Rect width={150} height={150} x={100} y={100} fill="green" globalCompositeOperation= 'destination-out' />
</Layer>
```

[image]

Comment: Such a perfect solution. Thank you very very much  ❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️

Comment: No problem Nyi - glad I could help! =)